# how to restore selected tables when back button clicked: jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

**Summary:** I have ***a.html*** page which consists of add button and a table. When add button is clicked, rows are added to the table. and when done button is clicked it collects all the values in the rows and redirects to b.html. When user clicks the back button from the ***b.html***. It should redirects to a.html and should restore all the rows to the table.

here is ***a.html***

```
<div class="report">
    <div class="panel">
    <div>
    <button type="button" class="add btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to configuration list.">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Add
                    </button>
                </div>

            <div class ="configuration-table panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Remove</th>
                            <th>Layer</th>
                            <th>Display</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th>Dataset</th>
                            <th>Ordering</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
</div>

    <div class = "done">
    <input class="btn btn-success" formaction="{% url 'b.html' %}" formmethod="post" type="submit" value="Done"></input>
    </div>
```

and here is jquery for a.html

```
var arr = [];
$('.report')
        .on('click','.add', function(){
           $(this)
             .parents('.report')
             .find('.configuration-table tbody')
             .append(
              '<tr>'+                  
               '<td data-cell="value1">A</td>'+
               '<td data-cell="value2">B</td>'+
               '<td data-cell="value3">C</td>'+
               '</tr>'
                }
      });
.on('submit', '.done', function(){
 // collects all the values from the table columns for each row and sends to other page using form action 
});
```

**Issue:** How could i retrieve the previous selections from the table when user hits the back button in ***b.html***. I am using python django 
I am looking for logic here.
Thanks

Comment: Once you move to another page, the current DOM is destroyed. Coming back to the same page would not automatically create the dynamic elements which were added via an event. You would need to raise document.ready to add them again.